# Python len() function adding 1 more

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried googling this with no success, but I am trying to read in a file and find the length of each string. Each string is a set of numbers (i.e. 012345). I use the len() function and it works but it is adding 1 more to every line except the last line. I am assuming it is counting the eol/return character. How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: What are you using to read in the file? `for line in file`? `file.readlines()`? `file.read()`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is counting `\n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can strip the whitespace:

```
len(line.strip())
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'One
Two' | python -c 'for line in __import__("sys").stdin: print(len(line))'
4
4
$ echo 'One
Two' | python -c 'for line in __import__("sys").stdin: print(len(line.strip()))'
3
3
```

[`str.strip` docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: Important detail to note, the newline character `\n` at the end of a line is considered whitespace. If that's all you want to remove, you can use `line.rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: @MarkRansom which to my surprise is 2.5 times less efficient, as a simple timeit on `'Hello\n'` shows :)

Comment: I doubt stripping new lines is ever going to become a bottleneck

Comment: @jamylak Sure :) But I thought there had to be some justification for writing longer code (provided it's functionally equivalent in the context, which it in fact isn't).

Comment: Well maybe we are interpreting someone's code written in [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language))...

Answer (score 2):

You could trim the whitespace off each line that you read. You can use the strip (strips extra whitespace off both left and right sides), or rstrip function (strips off whitespace from the right hand side) for this.

```
"My file line.\n".rstrip()
```

The rstrip() function can also take in arguments, if you want to strip, say, only newline characters.

```
"My file line.\n".rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Python's string replace function? It would go something like this:

```
len(yourString.replace('\n', ''));
```

Comment: Note that some OS use `\r\n` as newline.

Comment: ...but on those systems (i.e. Windows) you'd only see both characters if you explicitly open the file in binary mode, right?

Comment: … or if you opened it in text mode without universal newlines (and the newlines were inconsistent or for some other reason the heuristics guessed Unix instead of Windows)…

Comment: Also, even though you _can_ do this… why would you? If you want to strip newlines off the end of a line, why replace newlines throughout the line? It's less explicit about its meaning (and the common justifications for violating Python idioms don't apply here, since it's more verbose, probably slower, etc. as well).